# Custom meta field don't give me numerical value

Tags: post-meta

I'm trying to use the jquery plugin Timeago.
With this, I want to countdown from a date (2013/03/04 format) Which is in a custom field. 
Echo $Begin2 gives me something like : 34 days ago. It's work fine.

The problem is I want to take the number "34" as a numerical value. With the following code, `echo $Nombre` gives me "0". I think it's because `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Begin', true);` is not a numerical value ?

```
   $Begin = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Begin', true);
   $Begin2 = '<abbr class="timeago" title="'.$Begin.'">'.$Begin.'</abbr>';
   echo $Begin2;
   $Nombre = (int) substr($Begin, 0, strpos($Begin, ' '));
   echo $Nombre;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Correct way to convert string to integer 
$begin = '34';
$number = (int)$begin;
var_dump( $number );
int 34

//Another correct way to convert string to integer
$number = (int)get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'begin', true );
var_dump( $number );
int 34

//strops() = Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.
// returns the numeric position or false if not found
$var = strpos( $begin, ' ');
var_dump( $var );
boolean false

//substr() = Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.
//Your passing 0 as start and since false gets interpreted as 0 your passing 0 as length
$substring = substr( $begin, 0, false );
var_dump( $substring );
string ' '

//Same thing here but your converting the returned empty string into an integer which returns 0
$substring = (int)substr( $begin, 0, false );
var_dump( $substring );
int  0
```